# call-command - How to call a program file in an other directory

Tags: batch-file

scripting, its not my general terrain. I just wanted to adjust a batch-file under windows. How can i start a program that doesn't lies in the root-director with a call-command???

for example I'm trying to do:

**call java -cp ....**

to this

**call ../jre1.8.0_45_Windows/bin/java -cp ....**

But it says than when i run the .bat-file that "-cp" is misspelled or could not have been found. That means it doesn't work like the behavior before...

Can someone help me? In advance thank you very much!

**Solution:** 
It worked when i set the path in double quotes: 
call "../jre1.8.0_45_Windows/bin/java" -cp .... 
or using the posted command for my special case: 
%~dp0..\jre1.8.0_45_Windows\bin\java -cp...

Comment: Actual DOS or just the command prompt? They're totally different things. Also, what is the exact error message you're getting? The way you worded it is confusing.

Comment: Are there are any spaces in your path. What happens when you throw double quotes around it?

Comment: thank you dustmouse. it works when i set it in double quotes... i dunno i hate windows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming re1.8.0_45_Windows is a subdirectory of the directory that your batch file is in, try this from your batch file:

```
%~dp0\..\jre1.8.0_45_Windows\bin\java -cp ....
```

This will specify the full path to your java executable because %~dp0 will resolve to the full path that your batch file exists in. I also removed CALL because it is not needed to run an executable from a batch file, and changed / to \ because it's more common in Windows environments.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. In command prompt, type the directory where your file resides, for example, if you have a file in D:/ directory, in command type
**D:**
and if you wish to traverse to a specific location in that directory, used '**cd**' 
for example: 
**D:> cd FolderName\path of the file**
you can also use "tab" key for displaying all the files in that directory.

Comment: its not that easy i think... the batch-file should be distributed on serveral pcs where the user decides where he put the folder with the including files. The path in the batch file is the relative path in the project folder to the JRE. What to do now? Hope you get what i mean :)